# colorizing ls output based on filename

Tags: freebsd, ls, colors, csh

i'm on freeBSD and trying to colorize `ls` output, so i've added

```
alias ls        ls -lhG
setenv LSCOLORS gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
```

to my `.cshrc`

and it works. but what i really want to - is to be able to colorize (for example) `*.pl` and `*.php` files different ways to quicly distiguish it.

Can i modify `LSCOLORS` some way to colorize files dependong on their name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can't, not with the default ls that ships with FreeBSD.

You can, however, install the `gnuls` port, which will give you `/usr/local/bin/gnuls`, which can be set to display colors of files by extension.